# Image Upload Django Admin

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm new to Django and need to upload an image through the admin to use on a portfolio site I am making. I am using sorl-thumbnail to have the images show up on the front end, however I don't know how to properly call them once they are uploaded or where to upload them to. Here is my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class CaseStudy(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="static")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title #makes title the link in admin
```

And here is an example how I use sorl-thumbnail in template:

```
{% thumbnail item.image "100x700" as im %}
<img style="margin:{{ im|margin:"100x700" }}" src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.x }}"     height="{{ im.y }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I am a Django noob.

Answer (score 0):

upload them to media, then setup your media serving (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development).